# How to handle different background and same scenario in gherkin

Tags: automation, background, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I am new to gherkin need your suggestion.
I have background step in feature file like below,

For iOS country displayed as United Kingdom (en)
For android country displayed as uk

eg: For Feature file Background is

1. Select country United Kingdom (en) or uk

either uk or united kingdom (en) text may appear during runtime if anyone is visible it should select one of this on application?

how this can be handled? using gherkin and stepdefinition

Answer (score 0):

Your gherkin scenario should only represent the business logic, whereas which text appears depending on the os is something technical. So you should have a gherkin step which only says `When the user selects United Kingdom`, then in the step definition you would try to find either `United Kingdom (en)` or `uk`